# Accessing JMX MBean from Java and executing routines

Tags: java, spring, jmx, mbeans

I have a object named `EXOB` which has multiple routines. `EXOB` is a `Spring bean` and I want to execute the routine named `routine1` which takes a `String` parameter. I have written this code till now:

```
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("URL");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("com.example.package:service=EXOB");
Object  Params[] = {"str"};
String  Sig[] = {String.class.getName()};
mbsc.invoke(mbeanName,"routine1",Params,Sig);
jmxc.close();
```

I am using `intellij` and it shows error at `invoke()` method as `cannot resolve symbol routine1`. Is the way in which I have written the code above wrong? How can I access a `JMX Mbean` and invoke a function inside it?

**I also wanted to know if the above approach to invoke a function inside a MBean is appropriate or if there is some better way to do it?**

**UPDATE:** **When I execute the above code nothing happens and the execution seems to get hanged while I am running it**

Also when I add following to the above code:

```
Set<ObjectName> names = new TreeSet<ObjectName>(mbsc.queryNames(null, null));
for (ObjectName name : names) {
  System.out.println("\tObjectName = " + name);
}
```

I get this as an output

```
ObjectName = com.example.package:service=EXOB
```

This is the `object` name that I am passing in my code above when I getting `mbeanName`. This EXOB has the routine called `routine1` which I want to invoke

Comment: routine1 must be a variable or a  field in your code, it's not there

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev `routine1` is the name of method inside `MBean` `EXOB` which I want to invoke.

Comment: Then make it a String: "routine1"

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev ok. I wanted to know if the above approach is correct for invoking the functions inside MBeans?

Answer (score 1):

javax.management package API defines two possible ways to access MBeans. The first one is like you do. The second one, if you have a Java interface that corresponds to the management interface for the MBean, is via MBean proxy:

```
EXOBMBean exob = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbs, name, EXOBMBean.class);
exob.routine1();
```

The docs says: Using an MBean proxy is just a convenience. The second example ends up calling the same MBeanServer operations as the first one.

Comment: if I write `EXOBMBean` wouldn't it give undefined error?

Comment: Do I have to import anything for that and is mbs and name MBeanServerConnection name and ObjectName?

Comment: EXOBMBean must be an interface on server side, and you must have the same interface on client side a too for second option to work. name is ObjectName

Comment: there is no interface named EXOBMBean. EXOB is the object name which has routine called routine1.

Comment: The second way is for standard MBeans, it assumes that EXOB implements EXOBMBean on server side.